Parameterization of the reverse process in discrete state space paper
In section 3.3. of the paper Structured Denoising Diffusion Models in Discrete State-Spaces the author defines the following parameterization used in both the reverse and sampling process.
$$p_\theta(x_{t-1} | x_t) \propto \sum_{\tilde{x_0}} q(x_{t-1}, x_t | \tilde{x_0}) p_\theta(\tilde{x_0} | x_t)$$
I have a feeling I should be able to derive it using the Markov property and the rules of conditional probabilities, but I am having problems seeing how and why they introduce $q(x_{t-1}, x_t | \tilde{x_0})$, and arrive at the final result. Any help would be appreciated.
